# How to play Notification sound even in silent mode and return back to its stat

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to play notification sound even if silent mode is on

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(alarmSound);
notification.setSound(uri);
AudioManager mobileMode = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int previousNotificationVolume = mobileMode.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        if (ignoreSilent) {
            mobileMode.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, mobileMode.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION), 0);
        }
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(UNIQUE_ID, n);
        try {
            // to delay make a space to finish play sound before return back to original stat.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        mobileMode.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, previousNotificationVolume, 0);
```

This should be option that user enable or disable, I'm trying the code above but the things not going well, the sound heard "sometimes" and the phone return to the **Vibration** mode instead of silent, I want to handle lollipop case:

- In Silent mode , timed or indefinitely.
- In priority mode, timed or indefinitely.

In another world, I want something to save full stat and return it as it was.

Or, since I know how to play sound with media player, way to get the stat of phone, and if it is silent, make sound playing as a media, with max sound of media, the following how I can play sound with MediaPlayer :

```
public static void playSound(Context context, Uri alert) {
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
            final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And then like this (but I want to know if phone in silent or vibration or priority mode) :

```
if (ignoreSilent) {
                CoreServices.playSound(context, uri);
            } else {
                // else just follow normal behavior
                notification.setSound(uri);
            }
```

Finally, I prefer to solve by switching status, at least I will know how android deal things in this part, and working with API 14+.

Comment: Alarms are the only thing that will sound out during silent mode (volume to zero). However if the user set the phone to "none" interruption mode, even alarms will not sound.

Comment: @Populus In this case its user needs, but I want to solve problem for another cases.

Answer (score 0):

public void playSound(){

```
    final MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    Uri notification = null;
 try {
        notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        // mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, notification);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

        try {

            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
               /* if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                }*/
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                mMediaPlayer.start();

            }

        });

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```